# Removing from Linked Queue Recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion, queue

I've been given this linked queue code for removing an element from a linked queue structure in C. Normally I'd implement this differently, but this code is using recursion. Will it do what it's supposed to do, and why? And if it doesn't, is there a way to fix it so that it does? I'm really new to this recursion thing. Thanks!

```
typedef struct telement T;
struct telement{
    int value;
    T* next;
};

void Out (T **A){
    if ((*A)->next == NULL){
        printf("\n --I'm removing element with value %d.---", (*A)->value);
        (*A) = NULL;
        free(*A);
    }
    else{
        Out(&(*A)->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? If it's supposed to make coffee, then no it will not do that.

Comment: @immibis it recursively walks to the last node of a forward-linked list, sets the pointer that points to said-node to NULL, then frees the null pointer and leaks memory. In short, it is an exercise in recursion and pointer-to-pointer usage to perform a task in arguably the *least* efficient way possible. It is also guaranteed to invoke undefined behavior when executed on an empty (null pointer) queue.

Comment: @WhozCraig That is not what I asked. Re-read my comment.

Comment: @immibis gotcha. And here I thought the answer to that was in the title of the question. My bad.

Comment: @immibis I'm not sure I understand your question. It's supposed to do what any non-recursive function for removing a queue element would, like WhozCraig said. If you mean in details, than mostly I'm curious why you set something to NULL and then free it. This was given by the professor, but I can't figure out if he made a mistake there or what. Pretty much, what I'm asking is if this function removes the last element like it's supposed to, or if the pointer surgery is performed incorrectly.

Comment: @Denolth There are many non-recursive functions for removing queue elements, and some of them act like this one, and some don't.

Comment: @Denolth was it given as a "what's wrong with this dreadful code?" question? Eg: Find everything wrong with this and make it work correctly kinda-thing? I sincerely hope so, or I pray you course text is better than your professor's code.

Comment: @WhozCraig It wasn't =X This is the supposedly working code

Comment: @Denolth I'm sure it *appears* to work in terms of the list management, but in reality there is a blatant memory leak as immibis' answer shows. Also, unless you're using some sentinel-node construct (which I've never liked, as NULL is a damn-fine "sentinel" for "this thing is empty" imho), the opening deference (not the `*`, rather the `->`) will invoke undefined behavior if `*A` does not contain a valid, non-null pointer. The former of these can be fixed by swapping the order of the two final lines in the if-block. The latter requires a test of `*A` before doing anything else in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function does remove the last element. Note that at the last step of recursion, `A` will point to either the list head pointer, or the second-to-last element's `next` pointer.

It will then set this pointer to NULL, unlinking the last element from the list.

However, it will not free the last element because `free(NULL)` does nothing.

Comment: You might provide the answer to *how to fix it*